# INSERT INTO table different dates (dd-1, mm based on condition)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have simple INSERT like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_1
(FIX_DATA, VAR_DATA, DATE)
SELECT 'row1', t.value, g.value
FROM temp t, table_2 g
WHERE t.condition = g.condition
```

In table_1 I have few thousands values that are inserted based on above condition. But now I need to do INSERT in table_1 following this conditions:

1. If g.value '20.03.2017' then insert '19.07.2017' --> dd - 1 from g.value, mm - 1 from current month.
2. If g.value '20.07.2017' then insert '19.07.2017' --> dd - 1 from g.value, mm - 1 from current month.
3. If g.value '03.08.2017' then insert '02.08.2017' --> dd - 1 from g.value, mm of current month.
4. If g.value '03.03.2017' then insert '02.08.2017' --> dd - 1 from g.value, mm of current month.

Conclusion, day is always -1, and month is -1 if day < 4 and current month if day is => 4. Format is dd.mm.yyyy.

Any ideas how to do that?

Best regards.

Comment: I would place the select statement in a cursor. Then loop though the cursor using a record. When looping you can do an insert and modify values if you like.

Comment: have a look on CASE statements:
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `CASE` for that.

```
INSERT INTO table_1(FIX_DATA, VAR_DATA, DATE)
SELECT 'row1', t.value, 
   CASE WHEN EXTRACT(day FROM g.value) < 4 THEN -- create the first type of date from g.value
        ELSE -- create the second type of date from g.value
   END
FROM temp t
JOIN table_2 g on t.condition = g.condition
```

or you may use `UNION ALL` as well

```
INSERT INTO table_1(FIX_DATA, VAR_DATA, DATE)
SELECT 'row1', t.value, 
   -- create the first type of date from g.value
FROM temp t
JOIN table_2 g on t.condition = g.condition
WHERE EXTRACT(day FROM g.value) < 4
  UNION ALL
SELECT 'row1', t.value, 
   -- create the second type of date from g.value
FROM temp t
JOIN table_2 g on t.condition = g.condition
WHERE EXTRACT(day FROM g.value) >= 4
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

```
INSERT INTO table_1
(FIX_DATA, VAR_DATA, DATE)
SELECT 'row1', t.value, 
    CASE WHEN EXTRACT(day FROM g.value) < 4 THEN EXTRACT (day FROM g.value-1) || '.' || EXTRACT (month FROM sysdate) || '.' || EXTRACT (year FROM sysdate)
    ELSE EXTRACT (day FROM g.value-1) || '.' || EXTRACT (month FROM sysdate-1) || '.' || EXTRACT (year FROM sysdate) END
FROM temp t, table_2 g
WHERE t.condition = g.condition
```

Thank you all, br.